# What does "$$ = 1" mean in Bison/Yacc?

Tags: bison, yacc

Can anybody tell me what `{$$ = 0}` or `{$$ = 1}` or `{$$ = $1 +1}` mean in Bison/Yacc rule actions? I know what `$$ = $1` means in Bison.

Answer (score 7):

Bison is used for declaring rules of your grammar. Whatever is in the braces after the rule, it is the action to be taken when the rule applies to a certain group of tokens.

On the other hand, $$ stands for the semantic value of the grouping created under the respective rule.

Below I build a brief example based on your questions. The first expression states that the int_var derived from a NUM should be assigned the value that was assigned to NUM.

The second expression states that if: int_var is followed by a '=' which is followed by a 'FALSE' string, then the int_var token should be set to 0.  Then, when the int_token is followed by '=' and 'TRUE' then it is set to 1.

The 4th rule states that if an int_var is followed by a '++' string, then the value assigned to the token should be the value of the int_var found plus 1.

In the same manner, this can be applied to rules for different arithmetic expressions as the addition:

```
int_var:  NUM                 { $$ = $1       }
        | int_var '=' 'FALSE' { $$ = 0;       }
        | int_var '=' 'TRUE'  { $$ = 1;       }
        | int_var '++'        { $$ = $1 + 1;  }
        | int_var '+' int_var { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        ...
;
```

Hope this solves your question and good luck taming Bison.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  What I was really confused was from here - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/ch04.html under the "SQL Expressions".                val_list:  expr { $$ = 1; }
   | expr ',' val_list { $$ = 1 + $3; }
   ;

opt_val_list: /* nil */ { $$ = 0 }
   | val_list
   ;

Comment: I wish I could get a couple of SQL examples on these rules.  Thanks again.

Comment: By reading the book you sent, below the code example it explains that it is used for counting the elements on a list. This count will later be used to pop the elements from a stack. Therefore, if you have only one element then the count is set to 1 ($$=1). Then,  if the expr is followed by a comma and another list of elements then add one to the count of the rest of the list ($$ = 1 + $3). Finally, as the list is optional, then if it is empty, set the count value to zero ($$ = 0).

Hope this helps you out understanding the grammar rules for that particular case.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Is it required to count the elements ?